# ClassNotFound exception on missing built in java api

Tags: java, windows, macos, cross-platform

i have a GUI software that also uses the built in java apple API,
the problem is that i want it to run both on windows and OSX, but on the function where i use it, like this:

```
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
```

and

```
 try{//if osx

     Application.getApplication().setDockIconImage(
        new ImageIcon(url).getImage());
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

its still throwing the ClassNotFoundException even that its on try/catch 
is there a way to resolve that?

Comment: is the jar on your classpath?

Comment: How can you tell it's throwing a `ClassNotFoundException` if you are catching `Exception` and then doing nothing with it?

Comment: I can guarantee you that code is not throwing that exception. It catches and silently disposes it.

Comment: i see the exception on the console, its ClassNotFoundException

Comment: and its not catching it since its thrown from this line and printed to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that code won't run on a non-Mac system.  For example:

```
String osType = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if (osType.indexOf("mac") >= 0) {
    Application.getApplication().setDockIconImage(new ImageIcon(url).getImage()); 
}
```

Either remove the `import` and fully-qualify `Application` or move it all to a separate class that will only be loaded in this case.  For example:

```
if (osType.indexOf("mac") >= 0) {
    new MyMacSpecificStuff();
}
```

This will fix things at runtime.  If you also need it to compile on Windows, you'll need to use a stub for these Mac OS X classes.  See [here](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/#samplecode/AppleJavaExtensions/Introduction/Intro.html) for more information about that.

Comment: dont need to compile on windows, but i actually did what you said, i moved everything to another class and its still not helping, ill try the if now...

Comment: i feel stupid... tried to overkill it with a try/catch when it was a simple if....